# How to send the zip file in Rails via Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, grape-api, rubyzip

I have a set of files that are present in s3 and I have to zip them all and send the zipped file to the front end(ReactJS).

I am successfully able to create a folder in the tmp of the project and also zip them. Unfortunately, I get the error when I try to expand saying **Unable to expand**

Here is the code -

```
data = Zip::File.open(zip_file_name, ::Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  files.each do |file|
    zipfile.add(file, file_path)
  end
end
content_type "application/octet-stream"
header['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=abcd.zip"
env['api.format'] = :binary
File.open(zip_file_name, 'rb').read
```

Is there a way to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you expand the zip file when it is not served via Grape?